# How do I say "She's changed a lot"

Tags: grammar

Is there a colloquial way to say "A person has changed a lot"? 
For example, I'd like to say "I know she has changed over the past couple of years because of doing stand-up comedy"

Would it be 
"我知道他因为开始Stand－up就变了很多” or is it “有很多变化？”

Comment: Stand-Up would be **单人相声** & as for changed I think in Chinese it's best to be more specific as to *what* changed, her attitude? Her personality?

Answer (score 3):

Any time in doubt about how to put some expression into Chinese, check something like [jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com)

她变了很多 in this case would fit. But 她变化很大 would also be OK.

Answer (score 3):

I would word the sentence something like this:

> 我知道她之所以跟以前很不一样，是因为做了几年单人相声。

Where changed a lot is: `跟以前很不一样` - instead of being direct and talking about changed - we're going with a indirect 'very different'.

Also notice the `之所以...是因为` construct. Which would be like saying `the reason xxx`....`is because xxx`...
This is a common construct in Chinese and good for explaining things.

Comment: Google returned 538k usages for 单口相声, while 单人相声 returned 21.4k.